# How can I change this code so it prints on the same line?

Tags: java, printing, syntax, printf

I have written a little code, you type a number, lets say `123`. This number will be printed in the console in a bigger format.

How does the code work? It will get the input `123` in this case, then it will seperate this number and will know each digit. So it will know number `123` is made up of digits `1, 2, 3`.

Then check, if we have digit 1, then print 1 in bigger format, if we have digit 5, then 5 bigger etc.

Everything seems fine with my code but a huge problem is that as expected, each digit is printed under the other one.

I'd like to know what I have to do so every digit will be printed in same line so it looks better and more realistic?

I hope I don't have to change my entire code for this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Printer {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = input.nextInt();

        String number = String.valueOf(x);
        for(int i=0; i<number.length();i++){
            int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);

            if(j==0){
                System.out.println("  ###  ");
                System.out.println(" #   # ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" #   # ");
                System.out.println("  ###  ");
            }
            if(j==1){
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println(" ##  ");
                System.out.println("# #  ");
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println("  #  ");
                System.out.println("#####");
            }
            if(j==2){
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("      #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("#######");
            }
            if(j==3){
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("      #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("      #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
            }
            if(j==4){
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("#    # ");
                System.out.println("#    # ");
                System.out.println("#    # ");
                System.out.println("#######");
                System.out.println("     # ");
                System.out.println("     # ");
            }
            if(j==5){
                System.out.println("#######");
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("###### ");
                System.out.println("      #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
            }
            if(j==6){
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("#      ");
                System.out.println("###### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
            }
            if(j==7){
                System.out.println("#######");
                System.out.println("#    # ");
                System.out.println("    #  ");
                System.out.println("   #   ");
                System.out.println("  #    ");
                System.out.println("  #    ");
                System.out.println("  #    ");
            }
            if(j==8){
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
            }
            if(j==9){
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" ######");
                System.out.println("      #");
                System.out.println("#     #");
                System.out.println(" ##### ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if this is Android you can make textviews in a horizontal orientation and assign each textview for a number or just keep 1 textview.

Comment: Major changes to code would be required, because your code prints each digit separately, and there is no way to send cursor back to position where you intend to add consecutive digit. You need to construct your print outs dynamically based on input.

Comment: `"I hope I don't have to change my entire code for this?"` -- sorry, but you hoped wrong. Your code is hard-wired to print lines with newlines and only that. You're going to have to re-write.

Comment: Consider using arrays or ArrayLists to help solve this.

Comment: Oh no.. :( Alright thanks I have to learn arrays anyway one day I guess :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you are using println() which finishes its printing with a **newline**. And as you have noticed, that makes things really easy, as you just print the stars for one number; line by line.

If you now want to print the numbers "on the same" line; just a hint to get you going: draw that thing manually first. Use a pen and a piece of paper and make stars/dots yourself.

In other words: your code needs to be reworked in various aspects (no doubt, it will be more complicated in the end).

You have to think about things like:

- how many stars can I put on one line
- how can I represent my data so that I can put the stars for "row x" of digit y behind the stars for "row x" of digit z

Hint: one solution is to look into two-dim arrays. One such array per digit; the rows representing the different lines required for that digit, the columns representing the chars to actually print.

Hope is good enough to get you going.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that every time you call System.out.println(...) a new line is printed.  Since you're calling this for each letter you're not going to get the letters to line up.

To fix this, you could instead add Strings (or StringBuilders) line1, line2, ..., line7

and then, for example, instead of using System.out.println(...) for each letter, use:

```
if(j==0){
    line1 = line1 + "  ###  ";
    line2 = line2 + " #   # ";
    line3 = line3 + "#     #";
    line4 = line4 + "#     #";
    line5 = line5 + "#     #";
    line6 = line6 + " #   # ";
    line7 = line7 + "  ###  ";
}
```

etc.
Then at the end of the program call:

```
System.out.println(line1)
System.out.println(line2)
System.out.println(line3)
System.out.println(line4)
System.out.println(line5)
System.out.println(line6)
System.out.println(line7)
```

Comment: that's a nice way to keep the current code structure. still... eventually this student should learn about arrays and/or nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the mechanism used to display one digit, into a general method to print all the digits. You might starts by extracting the digits into a `String[][]` like

```
static final String[][] digits = { //
        { //
                "  ###  ", //
                " #   # ", //
                "#     #", //
                "#     #", //
                "#     #", //
                " #   # ", //
                "  ###  " //
        }, { //
                "  #  ", //
                " ##  ", //
                "# #  ", //
                "  #  ", //
                "  #  ", //
                "  #  ", //
                "#####" //
        }, { //
                " ##### ", //
                "#     #", //
                "      #", //
                " ##### ", //
                "#      ", //
                "#      ", //
                "#######" //
        }, { //
                " ##### ", //
                "#     #", //
                "      #", //
                " ##### ", //
                "      #", //
                "#     #", //
                " ##### ", //
        }, { //
                "#      ", //
                "#    # ", //
                "#    # ", //
                "#    # ", //
                "#######", //
                "     # ", //
                "     # " //
        }, { //
                "#######", //
                "#      ", //
                "#      ", //
                "###### ", //
                "      #", //
                "#     #", //
                " ##### " //
        }, { //
                " ##### ", //
                "#     #", //
                "#      ", //
                "###### ", //
                "#     #", //
                "#     #", //
                " ##### " //
        }, { //
                "#######", //
                "#    # ", //
                "    #  ", //
                "   #   ", //
                "  #    ", //
                "  #    ", //
                "  #    " //
        }, { //
                " ##### ", //
                "#     #", //
                "#     #", //
                " ##### ", //
                "#     #", //
                "#     #", //
                " ##### " //
        }, { //
                " ##### ", //
                "#     #", //
                "#     #", //
                " ######", //
                "      #", //
                "#     #", //
                " ##### " //
        } };
```

Then you can use it to build your lines like

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = input.nextInt();
String number = String.valueOf(x);
int lineHeight = digits[0].length;
for (int i = 0; i < lineHeight; i++) {
    for (char ch : number.toCharArray()) {
        int j = Character.digit(ch, 10);
        System.out.print(digits[j][i] + " "); // <-- add a space to separate digits
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of System.out.println("x");, just use System.out.print("x");